# how to print DateTime value

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I have this code and I want to print out the time as String without the 'T' character between date and time.

```
String datetime4 =new StringBuilder().append(date4).append(time4).toString();

DateTime newdt=new  DateTime(datetime4);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
newdt = formatter.parseDateTime(datetime4);
System.out.println(newdt);
```

Notice that `date4` and `time4` are String variables.
It will print:

```
2017-11-04T11:23:00.000+02:00
```

Comment: parse and reformat it using 2 diffrent dateFormats

Comment: why not use java8 LocalDateTime?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Where Comes the 'T' from?

Comment: Why not simple `System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(date4).append(" ").append(time4).toString());`

Comment: The 'T' comes from appending two different Strings

Comment: Because i need to check the difference between two DateTime values later

Comment: Are you using joda-time?

Comment: @Greg The 'T' doesn't Comes from the concatination. What you see is the internal presentation for a date. For calculating the differences you not need a string

Comment: Yes i'm using joda-time

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it:

```
    String date4 = "2017-02-02";
    String time4 = "12:00:00";

    //To parse it to Temporal object
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date4 +"T"+ time4);

    // to output it as String in a prefered format (Thanks @Hugo)
    System.out.println(dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

If you prefer Java 8 you will need to use formatter I think, LocalDateTime doesn't overload toString in the same way as JodaTime.

But not sure why you want to do this? seems like just appending both date and time is enough? Anyway if you want to parse to the date you need to put T as is needed to pass it as a valid date time format to DateTime as well as LocalDateTime if using Java8, then you can reformat it as you wish.

```
String date4 = "2017-02-02";
String time4 = "12:00:00";

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date4 +"T"+ time4);

System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 `LocalDateTime`;

```
LocalDateTime dateTime;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter desiredFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-01T12:10:10", formatter);
System.out.println(desiredFormat.format(dateTime));
```

Comment: Nice supplement to see the Java 8 version. For parsing you don’t need the formatter since the input string is already in the default format for `LocalDateTime` (it’s ISO 8601). `LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-01T12:10:10")` works too. Which version to use is mostly a matter of taste, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
System.out.println(newdt);
```

You're printing the `newdt` variable, and internally `println` calls the `toString()` method on the object.

As this variable's type is `DateTime`, this code outputs the result of `newdt.toString()`. And `Datetime.toString()` method uses a default format that contains the "T".

If you want the output `String` to have a different format, you can do something like this:

```
System.out.println(newdt.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

The output will be:

> 2017-11-04 11:23:00

*(without the "T")*

You can use this version of `toString` with any pattern accepted by  `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

You can also create another `DateTimeFormatter` for the format you want:

```
DateTimeFormatter withoutT = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(withoutT.print(newdt));
```

The output will be the same, it's up to you to choose.

Comment: Oh thanks for this, I didn't know that toString accepts a pattern. Nice one, need to remember this one! Learn every day.

Comment: This version of `toString` is a nice shortcut. But you can also create another `DateTimeFormatter` (I've added this alternative to the answer).